# webapp2 under Apache (= without Google App Engine)

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, webapp2

I am trying to run webapp2 under Python with Apache and mod_wsgi - specifically: Wampserver for Windows 7 with Apache 2.2.22. So far, I have failed miserably. :-(

I used the following  example from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

When I save this file as `c:wamp\www\Python\hello.py`, and browse to `localhost/Python/hello.py`I get:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /python/hello.py was not found on this server.
```

However, let me state that mod_wsgi for Python within Apache seems to be running fine; the following code

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello from Python!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), 
        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

is located at `c:\wamp\www\Python\test.py`. When I go to `localhost/Python/test.py`, the browser says `Hello from Python!` as I would expect.

So far, I have only found out how to change the default name of the def (="application") to "something_else" by putting  the line

```
WSGICallableObject something_else
```

into `.htaccess`.

But how can I get Apache to accept the variable `app` as a callable object? (So far, I have used Python mainly for programming outside of the web, so I hope this is not a dumb question.)

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

Graham asked me about the mod_wsgi configuration I am using in Apache configuration files and where I am adding it. I added

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/python">
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler wsgi-script .py
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to `httpd.conf` right at the end of all the "LoadModule" lines.

Some additional info on my configuration: I am using mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so. (Of course I renamed it to `mod_wsgi.so` and placed it into `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\modules`.) My Python command line says this about the version: `Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32`. The wamp server I am using is 32 bit. My operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit SP1.

Hope this helps with the diagnosis...

Answer (score 7):

Install mod_wsgi from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows and configure your httpd.conf properly.

I assume you have already added these 2 lines:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGICallableObject app
```

Install py-setuptools from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools then install Modules for your python

```
easy_install WebOb
easy_install Paste
easy_install webapp2
```

Create virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/vhost/domains/mydomain/htdocs"
  ServerName a.mydomain.net
  WSGIScriptAlias / "/vhost/domains/mydomain/wsgi/main.py"
  Alias /static/ "/vhost/domains/mydomain/htdocs/static/"
</VirtualHost>
```

**File: main.py**

```
import webapp2

class Hello(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    self.response.out.write('hello world!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', Hello)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to install webapp2, WebOb, Paste prerequisites modules on hosting environment using pip or easy_install

2) Create wsgi.py file under website’s root folder (/var/www/website/wsgi.py).

```
#/var/www/website/wsgi.py
import webapp2
class Index(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        output = 'webapp2 running on apache2'
        self.response.headers = [('Content-type','text/plain'),('Content-length',str(len(output)))]
        self.response.out.write(output)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',Index)], debug=True)
```

3) Create apache2 configuration file under sites-available folder (/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/ website /wsgi.py"
</VirtualHost>
```

4) Add “website” alias to “/etc/hosts” file.

5) Run following command to enable “/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf”

```
a2ensite website.conf
```

6) Reload and restart apache2 web server

```
service apache2 reload 
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

7) Apache web-server will automatically load “website” configuration on restart webapp2.WSGIApplication instance will point to mod_wsgi "application".

## Please note above example is tested on an Ubuntu 13.10 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not tried:

```
 WSGICallableObject app
```

You could also change your code to say:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

and avoid needing to tell mod_wsgi to look for a different name.

Comment: Yes, I had tried `WSGICallableObject app` before asking the question. This gave me `404 Not Found The resource could not be found.` Your suggestion `application = webapp2...` is something I hadn't come up with. Unfortunately, it also gives me a 404.

Comment: Then add additional detail to your original question which shows the mod_wsgi configuration you are using in Apache configuration files and where you are adding it.

Comment: I have added these details in the question now. Is that enough information or do you need more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is DocumentRoot set to in your Apache configuration?

Comment: `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"`

Comment: Does that mean in the configuration snippet you gave, the Directory block is actually for "c:/wamp/www/python", or it it actually "MYWAMPPATH/www/python"?

Comment: Silly question. If you are saving the file as \MYWAMPPATH\www\Python\hello.py, why are you browsing to http://localhost/Python/test.py? Is that a typo? You should be going to http://localhost/python/hello.py. That is, not test.py in URL but hello.py. It must match the name of the file. I didn't see this before.

Comment: No, this is probably just a copy & paste fail on my behalf. Will correct this in the question.

Comment: Ok, I think I have removed any copy & paste inconsistencies by replacing the pseudo variable "WAMPSERVER" with the actual path names.

Comment: Try a URL with 'localhost/Python/hello.py/'. IOW, trailing slash. The problem may be that the way webapp2 is mapping URLs with mount point of '/' is incompatible with AddHandler way of setting up Apache. Is the 404 coming from Apache or webapp2?

Comment: Tried the trailing slashes, made no difference. About the source of the 404, `access.log` says: `127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2012:23:57:44 +0200] "GET /python/greet.py/ HTTP/1.1" 404 154`. `apache_error.log` warns me about a minor version difference: `[Tue Jul 17 23:57:02 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.
[Tue Jul 17 23:57:02 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.` Could this be the cause of my problems?

Comment: Version difference is not. I asked you, is the 404 coming from Apache or webapp2? Find out what a 404 page out of webapp2 looks like. Is that what it responds with, or is it an Apache one. Replace your webapp2 WSGI application with http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment and see if the WSGI script is even being called for the URLs being used.

Comment: 404 from webapp2 (directly, without using WSGI or Apache) says: `404 Not Found. The resource could not be found.` Since this is the same error message I got after trying your suggestion of using ` WSGICallableObject app` in `.htaccess`, is it safe to conclude that the message comes from webapp2 in _both_ cases? Also tried your other suggestion of displaying the request environment. Got a server error 500 until I commented out lines 13 and 14: `    print >> output, "UID: %s" % os.getuid()``print >> output, "GID: %s" % os.getgid()`

Comment: After commenting these lines out, I got a long list of environment variables in the browser. So, if the problem is within the turf of webapp2 - as it seems to me - what do I do next? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: WSGI applications are meant to use SCRIPT_NAME and more specifically PATH_INFO to resolve URL. If webapp2 is being naughty and using REQUEST_URI, then it may not be possible to use webapp2 at a sub URL, or perhaps not at least at one resolved using AddHandler in Apache. Unfortunately it is using WebOb so I cant work out what it is using. You might try: webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/hello.py', MainPage)] as PATH_INFO for AddHandler will likely be that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself just yet, but have you created another Python module, say runme.py, with the following code:

```
def main():
  run_wsgi_app(yourmodule.app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

(Note: I got this from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/migrate27#wsgi

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I checked out the page you are referring to. Unfortunately, I have no `yourmodule.app` as I am working _without_ Google App Engine. Furthermore, this wouldn't even be the correct solution if I were working _with_ GAE, as this the piece of code that is supposed to be **commented out** when you are migrating to Python 2.7. So this would even be wrong if I were trying to connect to GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The line

`app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)`

should  be:

`app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/Python/hello.py', MainPage)], debug=True)`

and then everything works! Arghh!

Many thanks to Graham for patiently pushing me in the right direction: The problem was indeed within the bounds of webapp2, as soon as WSGICallableObject was set to "app"!

For the benefit of anyone being stuck on a similar routing problem with webapp2: Check out http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html. The first example on "simple routes" made me rewrite my call to `webapp.WSGIApplication` within minutes!

**Update**

Unfortunately, the above solution doesn't seem to be reliable: Today, I sometimes got a correct response from webapp2, and sometimes I got a 404 from webapp2.

Without changing a single line of code since yesterday.

I can't reproduce under what condition I get the 404 or the correct response. I am giving up on this for now. Which is sad, since I think that Python is such a cool language.

@Graham: Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: If that works it basically says that webapp2 is not a well behaved WSGI application as it is ignoring the mount point. It should only be resolving URLs relative to the mount point, which is passed in SCRIPT_NAME. IOW, they should be mapping PATH_INFO.

Comment: @Graham: webapp2 is clearly not well behaved: I removed my own "accept answer" check. (See update above.) I give up for now. I can't afford to toy around with this any longer, as I was evaluating Python/webapp2 for an important project. For my taste, this is clearly not reliable enough yet. Which is a real pity, since Python is such a cool language.

But thanks for helping me.

Comment: Personally I would recommend you use Flask. It is a much superior WSGI framework which is small and easy to use. The webapp2 framework does not have such a good standing in the Python web community and is not as well known.