# Issues getting a Python script to run on apache server

Tags: python, apache, webapp2

So, I'm pretty new to setting up servers on VPS, but I've been working on it.  I have an apache server set up currently with my portfolio on it, and I have a Python 2.7 project that I'd like to include on it.  I've worked through a bunch of it, but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong now.

I went into the .conf file and added:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

That went inside the  tag

I also added:

```
<Directory "/var/www/site-name.com/public_html/portfolio_projects/">
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

So now, when I load the file that I'm looking for, it displays in the browser:

> Content-Type: text/html Content-Type: text/html

And that's it.

I'm using webapp2, because the project was originally developed using GoogleAppEngineLauncher.

I installed WebOb, Paste and webapp2, I assume successfully since I no longer get error messages about not being able to find dependencies.

The project works perfectly fine on my local machine.

I'm not really sure why running:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
```

Is literally printing "Content-Type: text/html" to the screen.  Beyond that, it's clearly neglecting to run the rest of the application as well.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [webapp2 under Apache (= without Google App Engine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471392/webapp2-under-apache-without-google-app-engine)